# weird behavior of array slice method on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, methods, slice

I found a very weird behavior of array when it's used within a class... I've been trying to figure out what's going on, but I couldn't wrap my head around. So this is what happened.

```
class wtf{
  constructor(){
    this.array=[0,2,3];
    this.fn=this.fn.bind(this);
  }
  fn(){
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,this.length));// will print [0,2,3]
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,this.length-1));// will print an empty array
  }
}
const k=new wtf();
k.fn();
```

It works totally fine when I try to get the entire array using `this.array.slice(0,this.length)`. It will give me the full array. But then when I try to use `this.array.slice(0,this.length-1)` to get an array not including the last element, it will give me an empty array instead of what I wanted. It seems it only happens when it's written within an object method. Because it works fine normally.

```
const array=[0,2,3];
console.log(array.slice(0,this.length-1)); // will print [0,2]
```

I tried to delete `bind` method to see if this is affecting the behavior, but it still gives me the same result...

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

you code is wrong, put `this.array.length -1`

this.length is `undefined`

From your conversation I found, you are trying to inherit DOM `Array`

Try to inherit Array like this

```
class MyArray extends Array {
   constructor(props){
    super();
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) this.push(arguments[i]);
   }
}

const k=new MyArray(5,6,7,8);
console.log(k.length);
```

Comment: yes, I know that the second parameter is not a length, but we can still use the length of an array to find the last index+1 of the array tho...

Comment: no, f you pass 1, 3 --- 1 will be assumed as index, 3 will be assumed as position, I quoted the example in the answer

Comment: my question was not about indexing... I know what your talking about. But my indexing is correct. array.slice(0,this.length) give me the full array because slice method is not inclusive of the second argument, and array.slice(0,this.length-1) give me array without the last element because it's not including item on last index. But my question is that it does not work as it should when it is used within the object method.

Comment: got it, I give the answer now :)

Comment: thanks for answering, and it works! But now I have one more question..
`
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];
console.log(animals.slice(0, this.length-2));
`
this one prints ['ant', 'bison', 'camel'], so what is "this" pointing at?... isn't "this" pointing at the array which called the method?

and when I use it within an object, why is "this" pointing at the object that I created?

Comment: this will be pointing the the `class` instance, if `person` is class saying `class person`, then `this` will be pointing the instance of the `class`

Comment: if you really want to create an class definition deriving from an DOM array, then you should try to inherit the DOM array class

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with 'this' keyword inside the slice method. It is trying to find the length property on the object which is 'undefined'. Also undefined - 1 results in NaN

your code is the same as following code:

```
class wtf{
  constructor(){
    this.array=[0,2,3];
  }
  fn(){
   let length = this.array.length
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,undefined));// undefined because length is not defined on the object
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,NaN));// NaN because undefined-1 is NaN
  }
}
const k=new wtf();
k.fn();
```

Instead, Try this:

```
class wtf{
  constructor(){
    this.array=[0,2,3];
  }
  fn(){
   let length = this.array.length
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,length)); // logs [0,2,3]
    console.log(this.array.slice(0,length-1)); // logs [0,2]
  }
}
const k=new wtf();
k.fn();
```